# How do I import a series of String data into a list, without manually putting the " " sign to each item added to the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie in python.
Basically what I wanted to achieve is:

**I have a block of sample data as shown here:**

384&cp54,cp170,cp285,cp401,cp517,cp633,cp748,cp864,cp980,cp1096,cp1205,cp1315,cp1424,cp1534,cp1643,cp1753,cp1862,cp1972,cp2082,cp2191,cp2301,cp2410,cp2520,cp2630,cp2739,cp2849,cp2958,cp3068,cp3178,cp3287,cp3342,cp3397,cp3451,cp3506,cp3561,cp3616,cp3671,cp3725,cp3780,cp3835&hp21,hp37,hp49,hp58,hp66,hp73,hp79,hp85,hp91,hp96,hp101,hp105,hp109,hp113,hp117,hp121,hp125,hp129,hp132,hp136,hp139,hp142,hp146,hp149,hp152,hp155,hp158,hp161,hp164,hp166,hp168-170,hp172-174,hp176-178,hp180

How do I code using python3 to achieve the following without having to manually to add the " " sign for each item after the comma.

**The desired outcome:**

```
datalist = list()
print(datalist)
```

Results:

```
['stritem1','stritem2','stritem3','stritem4'....etc]
```

Comment: `datalist.split(",")` could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
rawData = "384&cp54,cp170,cp285,cp401,cp517,cp633,cp748,cp864,cp980,cp1096,cp1205,cp1315,cp1424,cp1534,cp1643,cp1753,cp1862,cp1972,cp2082,cp2191,cp2301,cp2410,cp2520,cp2630,cp2739,cp2849,cp2958,cp3068,cp3178,cp3287,cp3342,cp3397,cp3451,cp3506,cp3561,cp3616,cp3671,cp3725,cp3780,cp3835&hp21,hp37,hp49,hp58,hp66,hp73,hp79,hp85,hp91,hp96,hp101,hp105,hp109,hp113,hp117,hp121,hp125,hp129,hp132,hp136,hp139,hp142,hp146,hp149,hp152,hp155,hp158,hp161,hp164,hp166,hp168-170,hp172-174,hp176-178,hp180"

datalist = rawData.split(',')
print(datalist)
```